# Auto shutdown iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there a way to automatically shutdown an iPad after a certain time interval?

N.B. Not auto-sleep. Auto-shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. iOS does not include this feature. Most iDevices are only fully shut down if the owner doesn't charge it, and only rebooted during updates.

If you jailbreak it you may find something within the Cydia packages.

Note that there is no need to shut it down, unless you are storing it for an extended period.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do so with an unjailbroken iPad pr iPhone. The Auto Sleep feature is the only available feature of this kind at the moment.

If your device is jailbroken and you have Cydia installed on it, then you can enable auto shut down with a simple search in Cydia.

NOTE: The best way is always waiting for the new versions. WWDC 2015 takes place in San Francisco in June 8-12, and they will introduce the new versions of iOS and OS X which may allow you to do so without jailbreaking your iDevice.